# Why running a console app in VS for Mac also starts a browser tab to access a ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, orchardcms

Environment: Mac Book Laptop and  Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac, 
Steps to reproduce:

1. Checkout Orchard.Core (a ASP.NET Core application) from Github: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore
2. Build it and run it with "dotnet run", thus a ASP.NET Core is running on port 5000
3. Start Visual Studio
4. Create a new Console Application, add "Console.ReadLin();" as the last statement in the Main method
5. Press Run button to run this console application in Debug mode
6. The application is running in a Terminal and immediately, a web browser tab is opened and it opens localhost:5000

Comment: did you choose console application as  startup project?

Comment: Well, I only have the console application in the solution file, Orchard application is not in the solution, these two applications have not connection at all. Anyway, I did try set the console application as startup project, it still open the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the wrong setting for starting debug is selected:

[image: project_settings]

`Project settings` > `Debug` > `Start project` (instead of Start browser with URL).